# Prevent block of channel.send() if channel is in slow-mode cooldown

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have an issue with sending messages to a discord channel.

If the channel is in timeout due to discord channel cooldown, then the `channel.send(msg)` function will block. Is there any way to find the remaining time the cooldown has left or check if the `send()` function will be executed without blocking, before the actual function call?

```
# this.channels is an array of objects type discord.TextChannel, API reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#textchannel
for l_channel in this.channels:
    await l_channel.send(l_msg.text) # Blocks if channel is in cooldown due to slow mode, any way to check before sending?
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modifying the discord library:

- open http.py inside discord's module folder and replace

```py
if r.status == 429:
    if not r.headers.get('Via'):
    # Banned by Cloudflare more than likely.
        raise HTTPException(r, data)
```

on line 213, with:

```py
if r.status == 429:
    if not r.headers.get('Via') or data["code"] == 20016: # Or is in slow mode
    # Banned by Cloudflare more than likely.
        raise HTTPException(r, data)
```

This will cause an exception to be thrown that you can catch and the `channel.send()` function will not block.

Answer (score 0):

```
for l_channel in this.channels:
    delay = l_channel.slowmode_delay
    await l_channel.send(l_msg.text)
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

You can retrieve the delay with [this method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.slowmode_delay) and wait for the necessary time between each sending as I do in the code above.

Comment: unfortunately I can't delay like that, the sleep(2) is there because of API spam prevention not slow mode... I don't want the code to block at all because I want it to send to other channels as well without waiting for the first call to complete

Comment: I had indeed misunderstood the purpose. But unfortunately, you can't detect when a channel's cooldown is over.